# Android: Database data is not displayed

Tags: android, database

Help, the saved data to the database is not displayed. Here's the code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.compose_message);
        mDbHelper = new MessagesDBAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();

        btnRecipient = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_recipient_picker);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        editTextRecipient = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_recipient);
        editTextRecipient.setInputType(0);
        editTextNewMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_new_message);
        spinnerTimeDelay = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_delay);
        tv_details = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_details);

        spinnerTimeDelay.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerTimeDelay.setAdapter(aa);

        mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null://
            (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        if (mRowId==null) {
            Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
            mRowId=extras!=null ? extras.getLong(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID):null;
        }
        populateFields();

btnRecipient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
            }
        });

        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    // Spinner
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
        count=pos;
        if(FirstLoad){
            FirstLoad = false;
            return;                         
        }

        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You chose " + 
                  parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()+ " to delay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          return;
        }

    public  void showProgress () {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Sending Message .. ");
        dialog.show(); 
    }

    // Contact Picker    
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
            case (CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT):

                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor contactsCursor = managedQuery(contactData,
                            null, null, null, null);
                    if (contactsCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        String id = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                        String name = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String hasPhoneNumber = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                        sb.append(name);
                        if (Integer.parseInt(hasPhoneNumber) > 0) {
                            Uri myPhoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, id);
                            Cursor phoneCursor = managedQuery(
                                    myPhoneUri, null, null, null, null);
                            for (phoneCursor.moveToFirst(); !phoneCursor.isAfterLast(); phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                                String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                sb.append(phoneNumber);
                            }
                        } else {
                            sb.append("This contact doesn't have a phone number");
                        }
                        editTextRecipient.setText(sb.toString());
                    }
                }
                break;
            }


         btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNo = editTextRecipient.getText().toString();
                String message = editTextNewMessage.getText().toString(); 
                Log.d(phoneNo, message);
               saveState(phoneNo, message);
                boolean split = false;

                /*SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
                //String date = s.format(new Date());
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1900, c.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
                        c.get(Calendar.DATE), c.get(Calendar.HOUR), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), c.get(Calendar.SECOND), 0);
                //saveState(phoneNo, message);*/

                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                         "Your message " + "\"" + message + "\"" + " is sent to " +"\""+ phoneNo+"\"", 
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                Runnable showToastRunnable = new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      dialog.cancel();
                      toast.show();
                  }
              };

                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)  {
                    showProgress();
                    if (count == 0) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 0);
                      }
                      else if (count == 1) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 15000);
                      }
                      else if (count == 2) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 30000);
                      }
                      else if (count == 3) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 60000);
                      }
                }

                   // sendSMS(phoneNo, message, split); */
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });      
         mDbHelper.close();
    }

     private void populateFields() {
        if (mRowId!=null) {
            Cursor message=mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(message);
            editTextRecipient.setText(message.getString(message.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_RECIPIENT)));
            editTextNewMessage.setText(message.getString(message.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE)));
        }
     }

     private void saveState(String phoneNo, String message) {
         Log.i(phoneNo, message);

        if (mRowId==null) {
            long id = mDbHelper.createNote(phoneNo, message);
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, phoneNo, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the other one:

```
public class Inbox extends ListActivity {
    ListView list;

    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private MessagesDBAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Cursor mMessagesCursor;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.inbox);
            mDbHelper = new MessagesDBAdapter(this);
            mDbHelper.open();
            fillData();
            registerForContextMenu(getListView());

            list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        }

        private void fillData() {
            mMessagesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
            startManagingCursor(mMessagesCursor);
            String[] from = new String[]{MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_RECIPIENT, MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE};
            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tv_recipient, R.id.tv_details};
            SimpleCursorAdapter messages = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.message_custom_row, mMessagesCursor, from, to);
         }

         /*@Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
                menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
                switch(item.getItemId()) {
                    case INSERT_ID:
                        createNote();
                        return true;
                }

                return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
            }*/

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()) {
                case DELETE_ID:
                    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                    mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
                    fillData();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }

        private void createNote() {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, KAHTextApp.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            Cursor c = mMessagesCursor;
            c.moveToPosition(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, KAHTextApp.class);
            i.putExtra(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
            i.putExtra(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_RECIPIENT, c.getString(
                    c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_RECIPIENT)));
            i.putExtra(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE, c.getString(
                    c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE)));
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            switch(requestCode) {
                case ACTIVITY_CREATE:
                    String recipient = extras.getString(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_RECIPIENT);
                    String message = extras.getString(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE);
                    mDbHelper.createNote(recipient, message);
                    fillData();
                    break;
                case ACTIVITY_EDIT:
                    Long rowId = extras.getLong(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
                    if (rowId != null) {
                        String editTitle = extras.getString(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_RECIPIENT);
                        String editBody = extras.getString(MessagesDBAdapter.KEY_MESSAGE);
                        mDbHelper.updateNote(rowId, editTitle, editBody);
                    }
                    fillData();
                    break;
            }
        }
}
```

and then the database:

```
public class MessagesDBAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_RECIPIENT = "recipient";
    public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    private static final String TAG = "MessagesDBAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

     //Database creation sql statement

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
             "create table notes (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_RECIPIENT + " text not null, " + KEY_MESSAGE + " text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public MessagesDBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public MessagesDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public long createNote(String phoneNo, String message) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_RECIPIENT, phoneNo);
        initialValues.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);

        open();

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_RECIPIENT,
                KEY_MESSAGE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_RECIPIENT, KEY_MESSAGE}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String phoneNo, String message) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_RECIPIENT, phoneNo);
        args.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

I don't know what I missed, or deleted but the data is not saved in the database. Can anyone help me? There's no error here, the data is not just displayed in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

Your create a SimpleCursorAdapter, but you don't give it to the ListView. Add setListAdapter(messages) after creating the adapter in fillData().

Note: in a ListActivity, you can get the ListView using getListView(), you don't need to use findViewById(). This has nothing to do with your problem, its just an information :)